# How do I center this line of text?

Tags: html, css

I have a 'contact' page with three icons laid out horizontally for 'phone', 'email', and 'facebook'. Below each icon is some text, like the phone number, email address, and facebook link.

They're all centered up, except the email address text is bumped to the right a bit. I can't figure out whats causing it. Everything else is centered. Its probably something obvious that I am overlooking.

```css
#contact {
  clear: both;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  display: block;
}
#contact img {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#phone {
  background: yellow;
  width: 300px;
  height: 30px;
  display: block;
  float: left;
}
#email {
  background: cyan;
  width: 300px;
  height: 30px;
  display: block;
  float: left;
}
#fbc {
  background: pink;
  width: 300px;
  height: 30px;
  display: block;
  float: left;
}
#contactcont {
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  height: 350px;
  width: 960px;
  margin-left: auto;
  Margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<!--Contact-->
<div id="contact">
  <img src="Images/contactbanner.jpg" alt="contactbanner">

</div>
<a name="contanch"></a>
<div id="contactcont">
  <div id="phone">
    <img src="Images/phone.jpg" alt="phone" width="300" height="195">
    <br>
    <h5 align="center">1-800-759-5275</h5>
  </div>


  <div id="email">
    <img src="Images/email.jpg" alt="email" width="300" height="195">
    <br>
    <h5 align="center"><a href="mailto:sales@company.com">
      sales@company.com</a></h5>
  </div>

  <div id="fbc">
    <img src="Images/fbcont.jpg" alt="fbcont" width="300" height="195">
    <br>
    <h5 align="center"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/company/106888976?fref=ts" target="_blank">Like us on Facebook!</a></h5>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Looks like it is working as described for me... email is centered. What did "Inspect Element" tell you it was computing?

Answer (score 2):

After a quick look at your css it doesn't look to me like you are using text-align. If you use text-align:center in your css for each icons parent div you should get the result you are looking for.